# SQL select distinct when one column in and another column greater than

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the following dataset:

```
+---------------------+
| ID | NAME  | VALUE  |
+---------------------+
| 1  | a     | 0.2    |
| 1  | b     | 8      |  
| 1  | c     | 3.5    |
| 1  | d     | 2.2    |
| 2  | b     | 4      |
| 2  | c     | 0.5    |
| 2  | d     | 6      |
| 3  | a     | 2      |
| 3  | b     | 4      |
| 3  | c     | 3.6    |
| 3  | d     | 0.2    |
+---------------------+
```

I'm tying to develop a `sql` select statement that returns the top or distinct ID where NAME 'a' and 'b' both exist and both of the corresponding VALUE's are >= '1'.  Thus, the desired output would be:

```
+---------------------+
| ID | NAME  | VALUE  |
+---------------------+
| 3  | a     | 2      |
+----+-------+--------+
```

Appreciate any assistance anyone can provide.

Comment: dbms name please

Comment: sql management studio 2012

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `MIN` window function and some condition to make it.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,
    MIN(CASE WHEN NAME = 'a' THEN [value] end) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) aVal,
    MIN(CASE WHEN NAME = 'b' THEN [value] end) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) bVal
    FROM T
) t1
WHERE aVal >1 and bVal >1 and aVal = [Value]
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0da2cca5f9fac574b37a997bc7f46b39)

Comment: Hi D-Shih, I'm afraid the code you've provided doesn't seem to work.  It allows non-'a' and -'b' values to occasionally come through.

Comment: Hi D-Shih, I've modified the 5th line of the code slighly to "FROM T WHERE NAME IN ('a','b')" and this works well.  The only case that it doesn't work for is when aVal = bVal.  If that happens, they both appear. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a `group by` and `having` query:

```
select id
from t
where name in ('a', 'b')
having count(*) = 2 and
       min(value) >= 1;
```

No subqueries or `join`s are necessary.

The `where` clause filters the data to only look at the "a" and "b" records.  The `count(*) = 2` checks that both exist.  If you can have duplicates, then use `count(distinct name) = 2`.

Then, you want the minimum value to be 1, so that is the final condition.

I am not sure why your desired results have the "a" row, but if you really want it, you can change the `select` to:

```
select id, 'a' as name,
       max(case when name = 'a' then value end) as value
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, appreciate you taking the time to respond. Unfortunately you're code isn't producing the output I'm after. It produces results when 'a' or 'b' is less than 1.  I'm actually executing the code in VBA, and I've opted for D-Shih's solution, combined with the slight amendment I made to the code to exclude non-'a' and -'b' result, after which I run a removeduplicates command.  It's pretty quick and provides the output I need so I'm content.  Appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @Peter . . . `min()` *cannot* produce results when either `value` is less than 1.  This seems like the simplest solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `in` and sub-query

```
select top 1 * from t
where t.id in
(
select id from t
where name in ('a','b')
group by id 
having sum(case when value>1 then 1 else 0)>=2
)
order by id
```